# Accessing windows credential manager using batch scripts

Tags: windows, batch-file, credentials-manager

I'm trying to access the NAS shared path credentials stored in windows credential manager. Is there any way to access those account details directly in batch scripts. Like to integrate batch scripts with windows credential manager.

Answer (score 1):

If you can settle on using Powershell scripts intead of batch scripts, the [CredentialManager](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/CredentialManager/2.0) powershell package provides a cmdlet `Get-StoredCredential` which allows you to get credentials from the credential manager by name:

```
$creds =  Get-StoredCredential -Target 'name-of-credential'
```

Comment: thanks Saaru, however I have a follow up question on this. When I run the command get-StoredCredential for a generic credential it is giving me the output which makes me agree that the credentials are getting fetched in object form.

However, when I use same command to fetch windows credential, it is giving me blank output. Is there any way to fetch windows credential? Also, can NAS shared path be configured and used under Generic credentials?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What [research did you do](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)?